# How to prevent postback in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html

On click of a button, I want to prevent postback so that the page does not refresh. I tried with below but doesn't prevent from postback. Any help?

```
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="return false">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Note**: I cannot (rather I am not using) use VF page for this. I am using the html inside the resource bundle and trying to make changes in it.

Comment: If you are looking for pure html and javascript solution then you can try posting on stackoverflow.com

Comment: There is a similar question, please have a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096170/button-with-no-postback

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a VisualForce page with VF controls. You can use a commandButton and use the `rerender` attribute to cause only a partial page reload. At the very least, you would want to show a message giving some feedback to the user.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!yourActionHere}" reRender="<id of the object to rerender>"
    value="Save"/>
```

Comment: no, i cannot use the apex command here due to the complex folder structure which has html & JS files in it. what if i want to go without apex tag?

Comment: Understood. It could be good to clarify in the question that you cannot use VisualForce for this :)

Comment: Done, i have updated the question for clear view. sorry.